# Having issues installing blackberry apps OTA on OS 5 simulators

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to test my bb app's OTA deployment using apache tomcat 5.5 in eclipse helios, i tried the OTA install from the blackberry OS 5, OS 6 and OS 7 simulators. The apps get downloaded and installed on the OS 6 and OS 7 emulators but all the OS 5 emulators keep giving me the ***HTTP Error 400: Bad request The server could not understand the page request or was unable to process it for some reason. Please try loading a different page.*** I have added a .htaccess file to the jad and cod files folder, still i get the same results.. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run MDS simulator if you want to access internet from Blackberry Simulator browser. You can find MDS simulator in \MDS\run.bat

Comment: +1 yes this is the exact answer i m facing problem for i think. Thanx\

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to what Kiran stated, you can also Right Click Project > Run As > Run Configuration > Click Simulator Tab > Select the option "Launch Mobile Data System Connection Service (MDS-CS) with simulator."

I personally find it better to do this than run MDS manually everytime.