# Load URL into webview and hide address bar

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

As i am newbie in BlackBerry development, i don't know what should i implement for the below problem:

I want to load web page inside the webview (Navigation should be within application) and hide the URL address bar of the webview.)

I know the solution we do in Android as to make webViewClient and load the same inside the WebView inside the Android. But i don't know about the exact solution for the BlackBerry.

One more thing, i have gone through [**`BrowserField`**](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Browser_field_1184788_11.jsp) demo but i am not able to load even this example:

[image]

### Update:

I am able to load the URL and below error is gone by starting simulator with **`MDS`** service.

Comment: Check this and [start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336738/having-issues-installing-blackberry-apps-ota-on-os-5-simulators/8337171#8337171) your MDS Simulator

Comment: @KiranKuppa Thanx Kiran, you are right about to start MDS Simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html) should be the right solution. Make sure that the simulator is correctly configured by accessing a web page in the blackberry browser.

Comment: thanx for the answer, but you know web page is correctly loading from browser application. Hope you got my point, i would like to give you a link for the [same problem in Android](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/), Still can you please give me a code or example link for BlackBerry?

Comment: +1 Thanx for your prompt answer and made a quick light. I have installed MDS service and started it, its working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Like this you can get:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
private ButtonField click;
private BrowserField browserField;  
private BasicEditField address;
private VerticalFieldManager ver;
public LoadingScreen() 
{       
    createGUI();                
}
private void createGUI() 
{
    ver=new VerticalFieldManager();
    address=new BasicEditField("Enter Address: ", "", 150, FIELD_HCENTER);//Enter here like "**http://www.google.com**"
    ver.add(address);
    click=new ButtonField("click");
    click.setFont(StartUp.font);
    click.setChangeListener(this);
    ver.add(click);
    add(ver);

    browserField=new BrowserField();
    add(browserField);
}
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
    if(click==field)
    {               
        browserField.requestContent(address.getText());
        delete(ver);
    }
}

protected boolean onSavePrompt() 
{
    return true;
}
public boolean onMenu(int instance) 
{
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but you know i am not able to load URL inside the simulator. As i am searching hard, i came to know i have to load MDS simulator, but i don't know even about it. Can you please let me know? I have already downloaded package for the same, run the exe but don't know what to do next? Can you please?

Comment: Thanx alishaik for your prompt answer, i am able to load simple url in browser, but can you please let me know how do i enable navigation made within application and hide the url? Any example please.

Answer (score 2):

Configure your default BrowserfieldConfig Class and load the browser into that class as shown below.

```
        BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);
        add(browserField);
        browserField.requestContent("http://www.google.co.in");
```

It will load the google page in a webview.