# Issue in Blackberry Simulator

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to access internet sites through Blackberry simulator and facing problem while trying with Blackberry 6, but everything is okay with Blackberry 7. Should there be any different settings required to do the trick.

Thanks,
Prakash

Comment: You will need to start your MDS simulator. Check this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336738/having-issues-installing-blackberry-apps-ota-on-os-5-simulators/8337171#8337171

Answer (score 0):

Run MDS simulator First:

- Right Click Project
- Run As
- Run Configuration
- Simulator
- Launch Mobile Data System Connection Service (MDS-CS) with simulator

Or run it manually from the path **"\MDS\run.bat"**